# Run coverage on test with subprocess

Tags: python, subprocess, code-coverage

Is there a way to test and report coverage on executable Python scripts?
With some initial research, I found [some guiding information in the documentation of the coverage package](https://coverage.readthedocs.io/en/stable/subprocess.html) but the doc was not sufficiently clear for me to get it working with my package requirements:

- I use Python 3.8 under both Windows and Linux.
- The Python installation runs in a virtual environment.
- The code should run on a CI, i.e. without any manual or system tweaking.

I did not get it working together with `subprocess` (or alternatively `exec`). My problem is that the scripts are never executed. The method to run the scripts does not really matter to me. The coverage package reports 0% coverage on the file example:

```
Name                  Stmts   Miss  Cover   Missing
---------------------------------------------------
scripts\__init__.py       0      0   100%
scripts\example.py        2      2     0%   1-3
scripts\scripts_test.py  14      1    93%   23
---------------------------------------------------
TOTAL                    16      3    81%
```

I am also annoyed by the fact that each file is opened in a separate window during the call to subprocess under Windows when using the flag `shell=True` (the meaning seems unclear to me).

## Code

**Example of a file to be tested**
This file shall be located in a subfolder called `scripts`. Let's call it `scripts/example.py` :

```
import numpy as np

print('My hello world example: ' + str(np.arange(3)))
```

The main file running the coverage on the tests looks as follows:

```
import coverage
import unittest
from pathlib import Path

if __name__ == '__main__':
    root_path = Path(__file__).resolve().parent

    coverage.process_startup()
    scripts_cov = coverage.Coverage(
        source=['scripts'], config_file=root_path / '.coveragerc')

    scripts_cov.start()
    test_suite = unittest.TestLoader().discover(
        root_path / 'scripts', pattern='scripts_*.py', top_level_dir=root_path)

    test_suite.run(result=unittest.TestResult())
    scripts_cov.stop()

    cov_rep = scripts_cov.report(show_missing=True, file=open('scripts_cov.txt', 'w'))
```

The test file - call it `scripts/scripts_test.py` - searches and runs all the scripts (here only `scripts/example.py`). Despite the fact that the contained code is not run I guess that the coverage package has difficulties processing it too:

```
import coverage
import unittest
from pathlib import Path
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE
# from subprocess import run, call


class TestScriptsAsSubprocess(unittest.TestCase):

    def test_scripts(self):
        # Run all research code
        scripts_folder = Path(Path(__name__).parent / 'scripts')
        for file in scripts_folder.glob('*.py'):
            file_name_and_path = str(file.absolute())

            # Source of trouble:
            print(*(Popen(file_name_and_path, stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE).communicate()))

            # Non-working alternatives:
            # run(file_name_and_path, shell=True)
            # call(file_name_and_path, shell=True)
            # exec(open(file_name_and_path).read())
```

Answer (score 0):

When you call `.Popen()`, prepend it with your python call

```sh
python3 -m coverage run
```

It's also usually worth separating the `.Popen()` call and `.communicate()` to get the outputs(s) and check the `.returncode`

```py
p = subprocess.Popen(
    "python3", "-m", "coverage", "run", file_name_and_path)
    stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE
)
out, err = p.communicate()
if p.returncode != 0:
    raise OSError(...)
```

You may find you also need to set the `cwd` field to ensure coverage appends

If you intend to handle other types of interpreted files (ie. shell scripts or perl), you might consider first checking what a file is with `file` and choosing a dedicated coverage tool for each, perhaps exporting to a common format to combine at the end

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, make the files both a library and executable with the `__name__` dunder check and moving the logic to a function .. this will allow you to *both* run them directly and *also* use normal unit testing against them

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3

def main():
    "normal run logic"

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code does work since you put `coverage.process_startup()` in the main file and not in "sitecustomize.py", as said in the documentation of "coverage".

"sitecustomize.py" or "usercustomize.py" will be imported on interpreter start-up by the `site` module, and this way ``coverage.process_startup()` will be loaded by the python interpreter run by your sub-process, and not just the main one.

Put "sitecustomize.py" in any of the site-package dirs, you can get it with `python -m site`. Or "usercustomize.py" in any of the user-package directories, which you can get with  `python -m site --user-site`. And put `import coverage; coverage.process_startup()` in the file you chose to use.